# Pentex African Killer Bees!

Tags: world-of-darkness, monster-design, werewolf-20th-anniversary, mage-20th-anniversary, vampire-20th-anniversary

Welcome to Pentex Labs! We have everything to destroy nature: Banes, Vampires, Reality Warpers!

Now, my boss wants to weaponize Bees. He wants them to be super deadly, he wants them to destroy cacao - because those pesky organic farmers destroy our profit margin from Wyrm-Cacao ground from fomori-maggot eggs. Customers claim it would be "tastier and ecologically more viable" - what the Eff?! Bossman decided that we shall show them how horrible this ecologically viable shall bee, so YOU get to work! Our last project to make killer bees hunting humans, [led by Kerr in the 1950s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africanized_bee), was a mild success until the pesky guy defected and crossed in less agressive sorts and told the people how to handle them safely and harvest the extra honey.

No errors like that this time! This time we want the most evil bees there is! As proposed base material we have these two: *[Apis cerana japonica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apis_cerana_japonica)* because they already make balls against hornets, showing good base traits for baneification and *[Apis dorsata laboriosa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apis_dorsata_laboriosa)*, because fricking 3 centimeter bees are humongus!

Primary goal is deadlyness against humans without heavy armor. Their Honey shall bee addicting and corrupted with Wyrm essence. Make sure they can reproduce, we don't want to create each single bee by itself, it's enough if we make some queens!

Bonus payments are due if they eat cacao plants whole and feed on humans. Extra Bonus if your swarm can kill one of those pesky, lunar crazed moggies in a one on one! For our own production, Bossman wants that his little robot slave should be able to harvest that addicting honey, but that shall be of no concearn for you. That's for the tech department to deal with later...

At your disposal shall bee:

- Dr. Frank N. Stein, Ex-Euthanatos (Entropy 4, Life 3, Prime 3).
- Prof. Dr. Bloodrder Mushed, Tzimisce (Gen 10, Vicissitude 4).
- Jack "Munches Manchineel" Smith, Black Spiral Dancer Theurge (Rituals 4, Summoning/Binding Rites).
- Darvey Hent, our lobbyist at the Ivory Coast to allow us to let the killer bees go free.

Get me your most evil beests you can manage!

<sub>Bee puns intended</sub>

Comment: That moment when you expect an answer from Trish to be given already, but Trish is the one asking here.

Comment: Voted to re-open because this is similar to the optimization questions that we see in D&D and other games. Is it silly? Sure, but there are clear criteria for how to rank answers.

Answer (score 4):

## The Mage alone is capable of making bees with addictive honey.

Simply put, all they need to do is take a Life 3 emotion manipulation effect, put it into a Charm with Prime 2, and then lock the charm-creation spell into the Life Patterns of the bees with Life 3. This would be a 3-dot Enhancement costing 6 freebie points, and would give the bees either 3 points of Permanent Paradox or 3 Paradox Flaws.

Now, if you want to kill werewolves with evil bees and this team of villains, what you’d want to do is have the Mage create giant bees with Life 3/Prime 2, have the vampire hybridise them with living humans using Vicissitude so that they’ll have human intelligence, then have the Black Spiral Dancer summon some Bane spirits and bind them into them to make them into Fomori.